# Warning for Xcode Capabilities for [project] may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, entitlements

I am new to Xcode. Just started a single view project and encountered following error.

Project name: Pitch Perfect
xcode version: 10.2.1
osx version: 10.14.5

```
:-1: Capabilities for Pitch Perfect may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the build settings editor. (in target 'Pitch Perfect')
```

changing install group/owner in build options

Signing area screenshot
[image]
[image]

[image: Screenshot added]

Comment: Select the project file 'Pitch Perfect' from the left side and post a screenshot of the signing area's screen shot so that the issue can be more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

go in the left tap you'll see a Blue file with the name of your project press on it, 
in Signing there will be a "Team", select one or create a new.

Comment: I'm not seeing a team here. or did you mean ios developer is a team?

Answer (score 6):

In the Navigator you can see a blue icon with your project name. Click there and search for the Singing & capabilities menu. There you'll find the team dropdown

EDIT:[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvHKk.jpg)

Comment: A screenshot would be worth a thousand words here

Answer (score 6):

In XCode follow the numbers from the image.
I hope it works!
[image]

also update the Bundle identifier to be a custom one. (same image), and from your code
[image]