# warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID vscode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code, virtualbox

I wanted to test my flutter app on ios. I didn't have mac so I installed catalina on Virtual box and run my project on VS Code but as i run `flutter run`, I got below error

```
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor.
```

I don't know what is causing this error. Upon googling solution of error. I got below solution, which is for Xcode. For some reason I'm unable to open my project in Xcode. How can we achieve the same with VS Code
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616260/7290043

**Complete Error**

```dart
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
/Users/danish/Documents/storeifie/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 35 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
/Users/danish/Documents/storeifie/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 35 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           79.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/danish/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/danish/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner'
    from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

Answer (score 0):

`'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found` usually occurs when the app is up and running in Android and you try to run it on iOS. Some developers might also encounter it while upgrading the Flutter version. This fatal error occurs while running the project on an updated iOS simulator.

There are some solutions that you could try to resolve this issue.

###### Solution 1:

There's a possibility that your PodFile is not picking the the configs and you need to change to it, see an example below:

Changing the following code in `PodFile` can solve the problem

`post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| target.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO' config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0' end end end`

to

`post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) end end`

###### Solution 2:

Some might encounter this error when changing channels from master/dev to beta/stable.

You might want to consider the following solution if this is the case:

1. Remove `ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec` with the command `rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec`
2. After removing `Flutter.podspec` your flutter will be cleaned.
3. Run your application.

###### Solution 3:

If the above mentioned solution doesn't work, try the following:

1. cd ios to get into the iOS directory of your flutter project.
2. Now deintegrate the pod via pod deintegrate
3. `rm Flutter/Flutter.podspec`
4. `rm podfile.lock`
5. `flutter clean`
6. `flutter run`

###### Solution 4:

If your issue is still not fixed, change the channel of your app from master to stable. Run the following commands at the terminal to change the channel:

1. `flutter channel stable`
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter run`